# How get autocomplete filled after an ActiveRecord Validation Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using Rails 3.2.5 with rails3-jquery-autocomplete.
My approach is: i have an attr_accessor called "supplier_name", and when the user fills the autocomplete and select the propper supplier, it fills the field "suplier_id" with the id of supplier.
When i created autocomplete fields for my forms, i found an issue, every time i was editing the record, the supplier_name attr_accessor becames empty. Inspecting the code, i could see that the hidden field "supplier_id" was filled correctly.

So, i fixed it this way, just an example:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :supplier
 ...
 attr_accessor :supplier_name
 attr_accessible :some_stuff, :supplier_name, :supplier_id, :some_other_stuffs

 validates :some_stuff, presence: true

 def supplier_name
  self.supplier_name.company_name unless self.new_record? rescue ""
 end
```

So, great! I Solved my issue editing BUT... If i'm creating a new record, submit, and forget to fill the field :some_stuff, the "supplier_name" will come empty, but the "supplier_id" will come correctly filled.

So, whats the best way to solve this issue?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of researchs, issue was solved replacing the method:

```
def supplier_name
 self.supplier_name.company_name unless self.new_record? rescue self
end
```

for

```
def supplier_name
 self.supplier_name.try(:company_name)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rescuing `self`.
It should work because it should return the same object you've submitted.

If that doesn't work, you could try adding a setter method like:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :supplier
 ...
 attr_accessor :supplier_name
 attr_accessible :some_stuff, :supplier_name, :supplier_id, :some_other_stuffs

 validates :some_stuff, presence: true

 def supplier_name
  self.supplier_name.company_name unless self.new_record? rescue self
 end

 def supplier_name=(supplier_name)
  supplier_name
 end
end
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunally the application keeps the same behaviour, no progress! :(

Comment: Thanks Ballona. The issue was solved replacing "self.supplier_name.company_name unless self.new_record? rescue self" for self.supplier_name.try(:company_name)